# C# Checking if a certain shape exists in Powerpoint

Tags: c#, shapes

I am trying to find out, if a certain Shape exists in a Powerpoint presentation. I am new to C# and not sure how to cycle through all the shapes. I tried through a `foreach` loop but got nowhere. Here is what I got:

```
using pptNS = Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint;

...

    pptNS.Slide pptSlide = null;
    bool shapeCheck = false;
    pptNS.Presentation pptPresentation = null;

try
    {
        // Create an instance of PowerPoint.
        powerpointApplication = new pptNS.ApplicationClass();

        pptPresentation = powerpointApplication.Presentations.Open([pptAddress]);

        foreach (pptNS.Shapes sh in pptSlide.Shapes)
        {
            if (sh.Title.Equals("SlideID"))
            {
                shapeCheck = true;
            }
        }
}
    catch (Exception ex)
```

But obviously this throws an `System.InvalidCastException`. Does somebody know what I should use instead of `pptSlide.Shapes`in the foreach loop? Or another method to check if a certain shape exists?

Comment: Is there a class called Shape?

Comment: Not as far as I can see, but like I said, I'm not experienced in C# so I might be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change this:

```
foreach (pptNS.Shapes sh in pptSlide.Shapes)
```

to this:

```
foreach (var sh in pptSlide.Shapes)
```

Comment: But how do I get to the Shape-name from there?